# Simplest way to extract data-attributes as an array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance

Lets say I have the following html nodes....

```
<span data-key="x"></span>
<span data-key="xx"></span>
<span data-key="xxx"></span>
```

Is there an elegant jQuery way to end up with a similar result that this returns? I keep reading how .each() loops are abused in jQuery so if there is a way I can do this with a selector call that would great.

```
    var keys = [];
    $('[data-key]').each(function() {
          keys.push($(this).attr('data-key'));
    });

    keys = ['x', 'xx', 'xxx']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wNyx7/)

```
var keys = $('[data-key]').map(function(){return $(this).data('key')}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew there was a jQuery way!